# how to get a specific coloumn with a specific id in my table -CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a specific coloumn with a specific id in my table with CodeIgniter
I tried the following:

`$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id));`

but it gives whole row; I just need that row with id =$id and just a coloumn names "name".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the column for CodeIgniter to select. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: $this->db->select('name');
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id));
sorry you mena this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->select('name')->where('id',$id)->get('my_table');

$result = $query->row();
```

`row()` returns only one row from the resultset. *the first one*